# SMTP Library with Custom Domains for Python

Tags: python, email, smtp, custom-domain

I'm trying to log into the SMTP server. The custom domain is not able to be recognized through the smtplib.SMTP host parameter.

Have Tried:

SMTP host for gmail domains

```
    # login smtp server
    # Issue
    server = smtplib.SMTP(host="smtp.gmail.com", port=587)
    #

    print(server)
    server.ehlo()
    server.starttls()
    print(username, email, app_password)
    server.login(username, app_password)
    print("logged in")
    server.sendmail(from_email, to_emails, msg_str)
    server.quit()
```

Not Working:

SMTP host for custom domain

```
    # login smtp server
    # Issue
    server = smtplib.SMTP(host="smtp.customDomain.io", port=587)
    #

    print(server)
    server.ehlo()
    server.starttls()
    print(username, email, app_password)
    server.login(username, app_password)
    print("logged in")
    server.sendmail(from_email, to_emails, msg_str)
    server.quit()
```

Comment: Have you checked the logs on the SMTP server for the custom domain, to see why it's rejecting the login?

Comment: I checked the logs from printing the variable server. server = smtplib.SMTP. However, there's no response from running this line.

Comment: I mean the logs on `smtp.customDomain.io`.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not getting any response from smtp.customDomain.io.

Comment: That sounds like a firewall problem.

Comment: That still didn't resolve the issue. However, thanks for your help!

Comment: Use a packet capture application like Wireshark to see where the connection is getting stuck.

Comment: Try manually with telnet, from the same machine where you run your Python code: `telnet smtp.customdomain.io 587`. You should see a SMTP greeting like "220 service ready" or such. Enter "ehlo me" and see if it replies. Use "quit" to get out. If there is no such server reply, check the port. Usually unencrypted SMTP runs on port 25, not 587. Your code looks like you want a plain connection and upgrade it to encrypted with `starttls`.